# Why do I not need to reference the relative path in my html file to load a javascript file with express js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm building my first project from scratch and as I'm setting it up I noticed that, using the relative path to my javascript file failed from my index.html file, but referencing it just by its name worked?

1. Attached directory structure. As you can see index.ejs is in `src/views` while my script is in `src/jscript`. This means my path should be `../jscript/index.js` from my index.ejs file.

[image]

2. Express JS file code

   ```
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const port = 9900

    app.use(express.static('src/img'))
    app.use(express.static('src/css'))
    app.use(express.static('src/jscript'))
    app.use(express.static('src/fonts'))

    app.set('views', 'src/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
      res.render('index')
    });
   ```
3. HTML that works

`<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>`

So to recap, my question is why does the above html script referencing the js file without the correct path work. I know it's probably the app.use static file that points to a directory but I just want to double check why that is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Relative URLs are resolved by the **browser** not the server.

The browser isn't requesting `/views/index.ejs` it is requesting `/`.

---

You also said `app.use(express.static('src/jscript'))` so the URL to `index.js` is `/index.js`.

---

`/` (URL of the HTML) + `index.js` (relative URL to the JS) = `/index.js` (URL of the JS).

Answer (score 0):

> it's probably the app.use static file that points to a directory

This is the exact right answer. Plus I suggest to refactor this app.use in a single liner:

```
app.use(express.static('src'));
```

And change the references accordingly in the views.

Please notice that usually the architecture has an `src` folder that compiles to a `public` one so you would place the `public` folder in the express.static declaration.